# Average of a certain part of an array

Tags: java

If I had an array filled with, for example, `players`, `playerScore`, `playerAge`... and there were multiple players, how would I get the average of all the `playerScores`. Could someone explain how I can read in all the values for just `playerScore?`

This is assuming I have all my getters and setters and I have a counter.

Comment: Getters and count works  right ?

Comment: Yes, everything works, I can read in the array, I just want to know the logic of how I can pick that certain data out.

Comment: based on your requirements ;) ?

Comment: If you have your getters, what is the problem? You do not know how to calculate an average?

Comment: Well is it as simple as that? getPlayerScore/counter?

Comment: Yes. Expect rounding errors, though. Especially if you're using `int`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Comment: you appear to be learning java. instead of arrays, use collections (for example List and LinkedList or ArrayList).  don't store different types in one list.  instead create a class that contains player, playerScore, et al. and store instances of that class in a collection

Comment: @DwB i really wouldn't consider it being good practice having multiple Lists containing the data for each player. Some sort of container class containing all the data for *one* player would be much better. Then just have a list of that.

Comment: @itzJanuary  Pay attention.  it is bad practice to have multiple lists.  only an idiot would suggest that.  I said make a class to contain the info for each player and store that in the list.

Comment: @DwB oh, sorry. Misread your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

(*Cannot comment so please excuse me answering*)

I assume you have an `int` array that contains the interleaved data (, so `{playerScore1, playerAge1, playerScore2, playerAge2, ...}`).

### So,

to get the average player score you just need to iterate over every *n*-th element, add them together and divide by how many there are (*shouldn't need to explain this*). For example if there are *2* other pieces of data *between* consecutive playerAge elements, you need to iterate over every *third* element.

That should be very straigt forward:

```
int[] playerData = ... //Your player data array
int num = 0;
double average = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < playerData.length; i += 3) {
    average += (double)playerData[i];
    num++;
}

average = average / (double)num;
```

### (But...)

you should really have some sort of class that holds the player data. Something along the line of `PlayerData` or `PlayerStats`. Then just fill your array with instances of the class with the data for each player.
*Then,* do as I showed above, but instead of iterating over some *n*-th object, iterator over every `PlayerData` instance, like:

```
PlayerData[] playerData = ... //Your player data array
int num = 0;
double average = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < playerData.length; i++ /* <- every element, not every third */) {
    PlayerData data = playerData[i];
    average += data.score;
    num++;
}

average = average / (double)num;
```